# WCF Service - Failed to Invoke service - JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

```
The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at InstantBankVerificationPostBackClient.PostBack(String data)
```

**Web.Config:**

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="DebugJSonBehavior" name="IBVWebService.InstantBankVerificationPostBack">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:64337/InstantBankVerificationPostBack.svc" 
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="IBVWebService.IInstantBankVerificationPostBack"
            behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DebugJSonBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Interface:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void PostBack(string data);
```

Comment: Can you post your calling code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I am getting this error because of using the WCF client tool which currently doesn't work with wcf using json. I tried with fiddle and i get something different HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Comment: WCFTestClient is for SOAP only, not REST.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7479609/745969